# Will there never be a cure for cancer?

Tags: medications, cancer, research, cure

They've yet to come up with anything except pumping you with poisons that merely give you an extra year or two to live while you suffer humiliating side-effects.

When you ask experts about why they've never come up with a cure, their answers are always the same "Cancer isn't one disease. It's a million different diseases. It would be like you want a single cure for infections." Well, infections do have a cure: antibiotics.

Another more modern excuse from top cancer researchers is that "Cancer is an evolutionary mechanism to protect the species gene pool". So is everything else we cure, right?

It seems the billions of dollars pushed into all this research is pointless. From the outside it looks as though these researchers don't try to understand what cancer even is, they just rely on trial and error and hope they find something that works.

Comment: Could I ask you to revise your question. Currently, your question is nothing more than a rant and instead of blaming *researchers, that don't understand cancer*, I get the impression that **you** do not understand how such a cancer works and how it is treated.

Comment: Related post: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55523/treatment-of-cancer

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Cancer researchers are the bestest smartest people in the world. You happy now?

Comment: No, I am not. We expect a certain degree of effort before a question is asked here. Cancer as a disease doesn't exist. Cancer is the excessive replication of mutated DNA. The body has mechanisms to detect mutated DNA which fail when it comes to cancer. As every cancer is different, it is currently not a treatment option to identify mutated DNA. Even if identified, the cancerous molecules would still need to be taken out of the body. Future cancer treatments will limit the replication of damaged DNA and future some sort of molecules (or nanobot) to extract damages DNA or even damaged cells from

Comment: [cont'd] body. We do not have enough understanding of how the molecular interaction of cancerous cells and healthy cells work in order to create such treatments. Big Pharma companies are working on similar solutions to extract proteins needed for mutations and thus combat cancer. From what I have heard from researchers in this area, clinical studies can be expected within the next 5 years.

Comment: They've been saying a cure for cancer is around the corner for about 60 years.

Comment: And cancer IS a disease. It's your own cells replicating and multiplying and are immune to the immune system. The only difference between what you call "different types of cancer" is where in the body it starts and how fast it multiplies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has only little understanding of cancer and asks question based on false assumptions. An answer to this question would have to explain what cancer is and talk about treatments. This is too extensive for a single question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rant without a real question, it uses offensive language and contains false premises.

Comment: I've edited a lot of the rudeness out of your question. I think you actually have a question underneath the anger. I'm not a cancer researcher, btw, but your characterization like "don't even bother" and "excuses" are inappropriate and unfair.

Answer (score 2):

Your question contains a number of over simplifications. Cancer isn't one disease. That's not an "excuse", it's a fact that was painfully learned by researchers who rolled up their sleeves to "cure cancer" and realized they had it wrong.

Second, "poisons" (I presume you mean chemotherapy) are not the only treatment. You ignored not only surgery and radiation, which work for some people, but immunotherapy, which is producing some astonishing results for some particular cancers (not just where they started to grow, but their genetics, affect whether immunotherapy will work.) This [2014 article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4038596/) talks about the research in that area and what has been learned. For melanoma, even stage 4 metastatic melanoma, projected survival time has gone from a small number of months to a decade or more, possibly to regaining the natural lifespan. One interesting sentence fragment:

> the availability of novel immunotherapies could potentially result in cancer turning into a controllable chronic disease in a considerable proportion of patients.

And the field has moved dramatically even since that paper was published.

I suggest reading [this Scientific American article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/can-we-truly-cure-cancer/) about what the phrase "cure cancer" involves. Yes, there are still a lot of people dying of cancer - I've been to my share of funerals - but there are plenty living with it and eventually dying of something else.

Comment: While I appreciate your effort, I think that OP only wants to rant about cancer researchers. This is why this doesn't really answer the question, there was none in the beginning. (still +1 for trying to save the post by edit and answer). I fear that the post will be deleted because it really is nothing but a rant.

Comment: adding a link so these two questions are connected: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/13432/400